# cakephp redirect doesn't work on server

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

On my PC with WAMP server and php 5.3.9 everything works fine.

When I upload it to server with php 5.2.1.7 all redirects stop working - when the ->redirect(..) is executed script stops working - it acts like there was `die;` instead of redirect and nothing is printed and redirect doesnt work.

These are redirects I am using:

```
$this->redirect( array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login') );
$this->redirect( $this->referer() )
```

Both (in fact all...) stopped working after upload to server...

------ edit

I managed to show E_ALL errors and for example if I write `$omg->lol()` before redirect the error is reported as

Notice (8): Undefined variable: omg [APP/Controller/LanguagesController.php, line 31]
Fatal error: Call to a member function lol() on a non-object in ...

But still no error message for redirect...

Comment: Check your apache error log. Also check whether AllowOverride in the apache configuration is correctly set for .htaccess. Alternatively turn on PHP error reporting.

Comment: How I can do it? I only have ftp access...

Comment: I tried for example this: `<?php 
 header( 'Location: http://www.google.com/' ) ;
?>` and it works fine...

Comment: try adding `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);` at the beginning of the index.php

Comment: Or maybe your hoster has a control panel where you can turn on PHP error reporting.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix it!
The problem was that few php files had some tabs or whitespaces before `<?php` tags and after `?>` tags - when I deleted them everything works fine - damn PHP is real bitch!!!